# Subdomain in Symfony gives Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, symfony, internal-server-error

I have a Symfony project (example.com) and added a subdomain (demo.example.com) pointing to the same app. The subdomain gives an Internal Server Error. The error log shows: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

I set op my routing.yml like this:

```
account_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "{subdomain}.{domain}"
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Default:loginRedirect
    requirements:
        subdomain: demo|myaccount

homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Default:loginRedirect
```

Based on the Symfony docs in [How to Match a Route Based on the Host](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html).
Similar questions seem to point to the .htaccess file but I used the htaccess file shipped with Symfony:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

What is the way to go to get subdomains working in my project?

Comment: It's webserver log and you didn't paste most important part of code: how you setup the subdomain.

Comment: I setup the subdomain in DirectAdmin. Adding the subdomain in routing.yml, assuming that would be the way to go.

Comment: I tested your config via hiawatha webserver and everything working well. Note that to match the route with `{domain}` placeholder you have to add `domain` to `requirements` settings.

Comment: I added domain to requirements settings. Things work local but not in production. Creating a subdomain through DirectAdmin creates a subfolder with the name of the subdomain in public_html and in there is a index file. I am suspecting this has to do with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the subdomains to Domain Pointers in DirectAdmin so subdomain.example.com becomes an alias of example.com was the solution for my project.